# Developing GUI projects with MonoDevelop on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mono, osx-snow-leopard, monodevelop

I just installed MonoDevelop on my Mac (Snow Leopard). I'm a .NET developer, but have no Mono experience.

I want to create a simple GUI app, but there doesn't seem to be a Gtk# 2.0 template under C#. There's one under VB.NET.

I've installed the latest [MonoTouch-enabled release](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mac_MonoTouch) (as I may want to try MonoTouch in the future).

Should I have a Gtk# 2.0 template under C#? If so, how can I install it?

Is Gtk# 2.0 the best option for MonoDevelop GUI apps, anyway?

**UPDATE**

I also get errors when attempting to open either of the Moonlight templates.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2
  at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) [0x00000]      
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInfo, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00254] in /Users/michael/Mono/md-release/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Projects/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProject.cs:144 
  at MonoDevelop.Moonlight.MoonlightProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in /Users/michael/Mono/md-release/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Moonlight/AssemblyInfo.cs:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK# is probably the best/easiest cross-platform toolkit right now, though Qt/Qyoto might be worthwhile if you can get the bindings to work.

The GTK# templates are not included in Mac, because they're part of the GTK# designer addin, and the GTK# designer doesn't work on Mac yet. However, you can create a new project and reference the GTK# assemblies, and write code by hand.

The Moonlight issue was fixed in SVN, and the next public build should work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to report your problem on the [project's mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monodevelop-list). You will be in contact with developer that can tell you what to try to identify the problem or if the problem is known.